# Macbook Pro 2018 -- T2 Chip -- Flashing Folder -- Brick after update Mojave -- No Activation Lock/EFI/Recover lock

Tags: startup, ssd, t2

I have a Macbook Pro 2018 (T2 Chip) failed to update while update the MacOS Mojave.

Currently, when I turn it on, it will have a flashing folder. Here are what I tried so far:

1. Using Apple Configurator: I put the brick Macbook Pro 2018 into DFU mode and perform Revise/Revive. After completed the Revive/Restore, the Macbook restart and went back to Flashing folder.
2. Go to MacOS Recovery Mode: performed reinstall MacOS but I failed after 3 minutes of the installation process. The Mac automatically restart and go back to the flashing folder.
3. Go to MacOS Recovery Mode: applied the TimeMachine Backup but It's also failed after 3-5 mins processing and the brick Macbook restart back to the flashing folder.
4. Boot from external USB: the security setting didn't allow me to boot from the external device. However, after go to Security Utility Boot, It said No administrator found on the Macbook.
5. Using FirstAid to repair the SSD (current SMART status is

I'm wondering if anyone experienced this issue and have any solution to come across? This is a gift from my relative for awhile and we couldn't retrieve the proof of purchase to go to Apple Service.

Thank you.

Comment: You should only have to provide proof of purchase if you're trying to unlock a Mac that's been explicitly locked. I've taken loads of secondhand Macs to Apple Stores and they've just repaired them.

Comment: @benwiggy: Thanks for the advise but unfortunately I don't have the proof of purchase from Apple since I bought this from my friend awhile ago.

Comment: That's my point: you shouldn't need one.

Comment: @benwiggy: Oh Nice! Thank you very much. I thought they asked for the Proof of purchase also for the repair. That's good to know. Thank you.